# The debugger is not properly installed SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have created Data Integration service project using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

I have installed SQL Server 2017 and Visual Studio Community Edition.

I created Simple SSIS Package which performs data load from csv file to SQL server table.

When I do ctrl+F5 (Execute without debugging) I am getting bellow error

> ===================================
>
> Unable to start debugging. The debugger is not properly installed. Run
>   setup to install or repair the debugger. (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger
>   iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>   at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32
>   flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow,
>   DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DtsPackagesFolderProjectFeature.ExecuteTaskOrPackage(ProjectItem
>   prjItem, String taskPath)
>
> ===================================
>
> Unable to start program 'DTS'.
>
> The debugger is not properly installed.  Cannot debug the requested
>   type of code.  Run setup to install or repair the debugger. (Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Debugger)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger
>   iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

But when I do just F5, it works fine i.e data successfully pushed into SQL server.

There is issue with Visual Studio debugger, I tried so many times repair and reinstall. Nothing helped.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: There's no `Visual Studio 2018`. SSIS is *not* contained in the Visual Studio 2017 installer anyway, you have to download the standalone SSDT installer. What did you actually do? Whid Visual Studio, SSDT versions did you install? Did you have any other versions installed *before* installing SSDT or VS ?

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message says anyway? Run the SSDT installer again and select `Repair` ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Visual Studio 15.7.2.  Didn't have it before.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yes its my mistake, I corrected to VS 2017. I tried to run installer again and repair not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has able to solve the issue with trial and error methods using different approaches available over the internet. I did almost spent one week of time in resolving and I am very happy in the end as the time spent was fruitful.

I did able to solve the issue with **SQL Server 2016** and **Visual Studio 2015** and respective **SSDT 2015**. I made sure I install every time as administrator (right-click on EXE and choose "Run as Administrator").

I followed these steps:

1. I uninstalled all SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Server 2017, Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT.
2. Deleted the folders

   ```
    C:\Users\tat84336\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
    C:\Users\tat84336\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   ```
3. Installed SQL Server 2016 (as administrator)
4. Installed SQL Server Management Studio - latest version (as administrator)
5. Installed Visual Studio 2015 (for me VS 2015 caused some missing DLL and I did repair - it started working fine)
6. Finally I installed Visual Studio Data Tools for 2015.

Please find the exes for installing VS2015, SSDT-2015 and SQL Server 2016 from [here](https://github.com/satishakumar/SSIS) and you can also download them from official sites through search.

And download SSMS from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

That error message is misleading.

When you run an SSIS package in SSDT with debugging (F5) if you look at Task Manager, you'll see ... dtsdebugger or something spin up and that's how we can visualize rows moving through Data Flows, inspect watches, check breakpoints, etc.

When you run an SSIS package without debugging, then you're running it at the command line which uses DTEXEC.exe. A sample command line would look something like

```
dtexec.exe /proj bin\Development\MyProject.ispac /pack MyPackage.dtsx /rep V
```

However, Microsoft would like to get paid for their work so running an SSIS outside of the debugger is disabled. This prevents people from developing solutions and having them run in an automated fashion.

DTEXEC checks whether the SQL Server Integration Services *Service* has been installed. The only way to get that service installed is to have the SQL Server media which is only available through authorized licensed channels.

- SSDT - Free to download and develop.
- SQL Server - Open up your wallet

Comment: The media is available for download since 2016 at least. You can just download the free SQL Server 2016 Developer edition.

Comment: I tried with developer edition , same debugger issue coming.

Comment: I have enterprise edition of Visual studio 2017, do I still need licensed SQL version?

Comment: Visual Studio is a different license from SQL Server

Comment: In terms of opening up your wallet I have VS 2017 Enterprise and my company pays almost $100 a month to MS for my licenses.   I have the ssis service but it isn't started and I can't start it because we are not allowed admin at my company.

Comment: I hear ya @renaissanceMan both in terms of licensing and the corporate security hassle. Whenever I take a role/contract at a larger firm, I always make sure they understand that as a developer, I need local admin rights. Period, full stop. Raise the issue with your management and if they do nothing, then they clearly don't see it as an issue and you can manage your expectations of efficiency appropriately.

Comment: billnkc, i actually went to the trouble to file a ticket so an admin would set my ssis, ssas, and ssrs services to automatic. it worked and they started, even through reboot, but it's not making my life better.  I'm getting a "To run a ssis package outside of Sql Server Data Tools ... " error message I thought maybe the service would fix but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is standard SSIS package behavior, do not worry.
There are the following debug capabilities for SSIS package:

- Set up a breakpoint on some of SSIS tasks. This allows to inspect variable contents. [MS Docs on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/troubleshooting/debugging-control-flow?view=sql-server-2017).
- Set up a data viewer in Data Flow task. This allows to check contents of Data Flow at specific path. [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/troubleshooting/debugging-data-flow?view=sql-server-2017).

Anyway, after you set up breakpoints or data viewers, run package in VS and wait until it hit the breakpoint or data viewer.

Comment: breakpoints and data viewer not working without debugging mode i.e ctrl + f5

Comment: This is NOT standard SSIS behavior when using Visual Studio. If you can't start the debug process how can you step through the package?